# Scroll view to left in android app

Tags: android, scrollview, right-to-left

in my app i have place a text view in the middle of the layout and when i scroll screen to left i want to show the google maps. So far i am showing the google aps by ontouch method.

how to perform this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a third party called [SwipeView](https://github.com/fry15/uk.co.jasonfry.android.tools).

It's an extension of the [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

USE THIS , its working fine and no delays

```
 hor = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
    hor.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            hor.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
        }
    }, 1L);
```